# What does "group measurements by" mean in the node Outlier Removal (Knime)?

Tags: boxplot, outliers, knime

I have imposed "box plot" as method and 1.5 as factor.

Node description tells:

**"Subsets**

Select the columns by which the measurements should be grouped (example: plates, batches, runs...)"

What is the function "group measurement by"? Aren't the outliers measured using Mean + IQR*(1.5) and Mean - IQR*(1.5) independentely of others columns?

Answer (score 0):

It means you do not need to group loop the table for each plate/batch/... (like in High Throughput Screening), but you can still find the outliers in those groups. In case you do not need groups, you can still not group by (or in case you have to, you can group by a constant column).